# Sql update for clob field in PDO (PHP) doesn't update nor throw update execption

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, clob

I've searched all over the net for examples on performing a sql update on clob fields; I believe the example I'm using is the simplest one that should work but so far none have worked.  I'm trying to insert a base64 encoded image into the clob field in oracle.  Below are the function and the array of clob entries.  I've checked the table and verified that no update has occurred on the clob field.

```
// update row with new clob values
private function clobUpdate($clobArray){
    try {
        foreach ($clobArray as $item) {
            $query = "UPDATE ". static::$table ." SET ". $item["clobField"] ." = EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE ID = :ID RETURNING ". $item["clobField"] . " INTO :blob";

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $item["id"]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':blob', $item["clobValue"], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $blob = NULL;
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->db->commit();
            print_r($blob);
            die();
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        throw new Exception($e);
    }

}


 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [clobField] => 0
        [clobValue] => data:image/png;base64,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
        [id] => 25
    )

)
```

***** update

Per Fred's error handling link and [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57095) 2007 patch I'm now able to update my clob.  Updated function below:

```
// update row with new clob values
private function clobUpdate($clobArray){
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        foreach ($clobArray as $item) {
            $query = "UPDATE ". static::$table ." SET ". $item["clobField"] ." = :CLOB WHERE ID = :ID";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $item["id"]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':CLOB', $item["clobValue"], PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($item["clobValue"]));
            $blob = NULL;
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->db->commit();
            print_r($blob);
            die();
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Exception ". $e->getMessage();
        throw new Exception($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `:ID` != `:id` and checking for errors would have thrown you something about it. *"doesn't update nor throw update execption"* - Probably because you're not using the right error checking method. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: `bindParam(':id',` => `bindParam(':ID',` - Those are case-sensitive.

Comment: Per your error handling link and this 2007 patch I'm now able to update my clob.  Updated function below:

Comment: problem solved then?

Comment: yes - tho I don't see where i can mark this answered.

Comment: actually, I'll post an answer but as a community wiki. Give me a minute.

Comment: I posted an answer below as a community wiki that you can mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTA: Posting as a community wiki to mark the question as solved.

You are using `:ID` and `:id`. Those are case-sensitive.

`WHERE ID = :ID` ... `bindParam(':id',` => `bindParam(':ID',`

- Use PDO's error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Yet, from the link you found about a patch, seems to also have contributed to successfully updating your database.

As per your comment:

> *"Per Fred's error handling link and [this 2007 patch](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57095) I'm now able to update my clob. Updated function below:"*

```
// update row with new clob values
private function clobUpdate($clobArray){
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        foreach ($clobArray as $item) {
            $query = "UPDATE ". static::$table ." SET ". $item["clobField"] ." = :CLOB WHERE ID = :ID";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $item["id"]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':CLOB', $item["clobValue"], PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($item["clobValue"]));
            $blob = NULL;
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->db->commit();
            print_r($blob);
            die();
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Exception ". $e->getMessage();
        throw new Exception($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - "you are using :ID and :id"; you mean in line 6?
           $query = "UPDATE ". static::$table ." SET ". $item["clobField"] ." = :CLOB WHERE ID = :ID";

Comment: @PatrickHaggood Yes. You were using `WHERE ID = :ID RETURNING` and then `bindParam(':id',` which should as read as `bindParam(':ID',` in uppercase. They are case-sensitive.

Comment: I got rid of 'RETURNING' in the updated function.  The example that used that and 'EMPTY BLOB()' were very confusing and I'm happy I could make it a simple update using the examples in the patch.  In my updated function I do use the correct case everywhere.

Comment: @PatrickHaggood Glad to hear it's been completely resolved Patrick, *cheers*